# Construction of the Čech-Stone compactification: why is $\iota$ an embedding?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, compactification

I have been reading a [post](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/03/18/245b-notes-13-compactification-and-metrisation-optional/#more-1901) on Terence Tao's blog about the Čech-Stone compactification.  He constructs a compactification as follows (see his exercise 3).  Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space.  Let $C\left(X,\left[0,1\right]\right)$ be the set of continuous functions from $X$ to $\left[0,1\right]$.  Let $Q=\left[0,1\right]^{C\left(X,\left[0,1\right]\right)}$ with the product topology. Let $\iota\colon X\rightarrow Q$ be given by $\iota\left(x\right)=\left(f\left(x\right)\right)_{f\in C\left(X,\left[0,1\right]\right)}$ for all $x\in X$.  Let $\beta X$ be the closure of $\iota\left(X\right)$ in $Q$.  Then $\left(\beta X,\iota\right)$ is a Čech-Stone compactification of $X$.

I'm trying to see why $\left(\beta X, \iota \right)$ is a compactification.  I am able to show that $\beta X$ is compact and that $\iota$ is a continuous bijection whose image is a dense subset of $\beta X$, but I have been unable to see why $\iota$ must be an embedding. In particular, suppose $X=\mathbb{N}$.  Then $\iota\left(\{0\} \right) = \{\left(f\left(0\right)\right)_{f\in C\left(\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \left[0,1\right]\right)}\}$, which is not, it seems to me, open in $\beta X$ as a subspace of $Q$ with the product topology.  I am sure I am misunderstanding something, as my topology experience is limited.

### Edit

My counterexample of $\iota\left(\{0\}\right)$ is wrong, as explained in the comments of @user254665's answer.  Implicitly, I was assuming that $\iota\left(\mathbb{N}\right) = \Pi_{f\in C\left(\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \left[0,1\right]\right)}f\left(\mathbb{N}\right)$, which is incorrect.  Moreover, the following argument shows that $\iota\left(\{0\}\right)$ is in fact open in $\iota\left(\mathbb{N}\right)$.  Let $f \colon \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \left[0,1\right]$ be given by $f\left(0\right)=1$ and $f\left(n\right)=0$ for $n\ne 0$. Let $U = \{q\in Q \vert q_{f}=1\}$.  Then $U$ is open in $\iota\left(\mathbb{N}\right) \subset Q$, $\iota\left(0\right) \in U$, and if $n\ne 0$ then $\iota\left(n\right) \notin U$.

Comment: The fact that $i$ is an embedding is theorem 4 in [this](http://individual.utoronto.ca/jordanbell/notes/stonecech.pdf) note. In particular, $\beta \mathbb N$ is zero dimensional. i.e. its base consists of clopen sets.

Comment: The Tychonoff product of a family of $T_n$ spaces is a $T_n$ space for $n<4$. And the Tychonoff product of compact spaces is a compact space ,(That is called the Tychonoff theorem). So $Q=[0,1]^{C(X,[0,1])}$ is a compact Hausdorff space and $\beta X$ is closed in $Q$, so $\beta X$ is compact. And $\beta X$ is $T_2$ as it is a subspace of the $T_2$ space $Q.$

Comment: Once we know that $i$ is a compactification, we know that $X$ is open in $iX$ whenever (and iff) $X$ is locally compact.  In particular when $X=\mathbb N.$

Comment: Nice explicit construction for $\beta X.$ The Wallman extension is $\beta X $ only when $X$ is normal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regardind the Q of why it is an embedding: Apply the Diagonal Theorem.

Let $F=\{f_s:A\to B_s\}_{s\in S}$ be a set of  functions.

We say $F$ separates points when there exists $f\in F$ with $f(a)\ne f(a')$ whenever $a,a'$ are distinct members of $A.$ We say $F$ separates closed sets from points when there exists  $f\in F$ with $f(a)\not \in Cl_{B_s}f(C)$ whenever $a\in A$ and $a\not \in C=Cl_A(C)\subset A.$

Theorem. If $F$ (as above) is a set of continuous functions, and separates points, and separates closed sets from points, then $\Delta (a)=(f_s(a))_{s\in S}$ is a homeomorphic embedding of $A$ into $\prod_{s\in S}B_s.$

See, for example, Engelking, General Topology, chapter 2: The paragraphs after Corollary 2.3.18, and Lemma 2.3.19 and Theorem 2.3.20.

Comment: This seems to apply, and the reference is very good.  There is still one thing I don't understand, and I would appreciate your insight if care to give it: what is the flaw in the proposed counterexample at the end of my question?  Specifically, since singleton sets are open in $\mathbb{N}$, the image of a singleton would have to be the intersection of an open set in $Q$ with the image $\iota X$.  Since there are infinitely many non-constant functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\left[0,1\right]$, it would seem that $f\left(\{0\}\right)$ doesn't qualify.  Perhaps this should be a separate question.

Comment: With $X=\mathbb N$, let $g:\mathbb N\to [0,1]$ be injective. For $n\in \mathbb N$ let $f_n(x)=g(n)$ for all $x\in [0,1].$ ....Let $v(n)\in Q$ where $v(n)(f_n)=1$ , and $v(n)(g)=0$  when $f_n\ne g\in C(\mathbb N,[0,1]). $..... Let  $S=C(\mathbb N,[0,1])$ for brevity. For each $n\in \mathbb N$ the set  $ \{(v_s)_{s\in S} \in Q: v_{f_n}=1\}$ is open in $Q$ and it contains $(h_s(n))_{s\in S}= i(n $)  but does not contain $ i(m)$ for $n\ne m \in \mathbb N.$

Comment: Thanks.  I'm working through your argument above.  I think the mistake in my counterexample was in assuming (implicitly) that $\beta \mathbb{N} = \Pi_{f\in S}\overline{f\left(\mathbb{N}\right)}$.

Comment: Also, for anyone reading these comments in the future, the $f\left(\{0\}\right)$ in the second-to-last sentence in my first comment should have been $\iota\left(\{0\}\right)$.  I seem unable to edit the comment.

Comment: Comments can only be edited for 5 minutes.

Comment: Here is a simplified version of the argument above from user254665: For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, let $f_n \colon \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \left[0,1\right]$ be given by $f_{n}\left(n\right)=1$ and $f_{n}\left(m\right)=0$ for $m\ne n$. Let $U_n = \{q\in Q \vert q_{f_n}=1\}$.  Then $U_n$ is open in $Q\cap \iota\left(\mathbb{N}\right)$, $\iota\left(n\right) \in U_n$, and if $m\ne n$ then $\iota\left(m\right) \notin U_n$.